# simple command line command has syntax error trying to import .sql file

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line, import, phpmyadmin

```
openextreme < 'www/downloads/official_games_db.sql'
```

That's the line.  I've tried it with and without quotes, double quotes, the full file path, just the file name, etc.  I want `official_games_db.sql` (a table) imported into the database `openextreme` (which does exist).  The file is good, as importing it through phpMyAdmin works flawlessly.  But for various reasons, I'm looking to get it done through the command line.

I keep getting error 1064, syntax, but no real help beyond that.  I've searched, and from what I can tell, I have it correct.  I've tried it with and without semicolon at the end too.  I'm at my wits end.  Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: from where are you running this command? It should be run from shell and not from MySQL command line. Also, the command should be `mysql -u username -p password openextreme < www/downloads/official_games_db.sql`

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between shell and MySQL command line.  I thought they were the same thing.  I'm running this on WAMP (I MUST use Windows for this project).  I've tried from the MySQL command line and from phpMyAdmin, as well as through AutoHotKey.  No joy.  Thanks for the help.  Let me try what you've suggested.

Comment: That's what's so frustrating.  I tried it from the console and from phpMyAdmin as written above (Virenda's approach).  Still getting the same 1064 error.

By all rights, this should work.  But the word 'should' exists for a reason, no?  Thanks for the help thus far.  Just need a little more apparently.

Comment: By shell I meant the login into server. Anyways, if you are using WAMP, you can use the import feature in PHPMyAdmin. No need to use this command. The only problem you might face is the max_upload_limit of you server, which you might have to change in your apache and/or php config.

Comment: Virenda, thanks for your help.  I've successfully imported using PHPMyadmin.  However, for the project I'm working on, I want to be able to do it with a command, which can be run from a script/batch file, which can be scheduled to run every 6 hours or 24 hours or whatever.  That's why I'm so focused on getting the command to work.  Any more thoughts?  You've been very helpful thus far.

Comment: To run the command from a script/batch file, you don't have to login into mysql, you can directly run the command from the shell window.

Answer (score 1):

mysql -u username -p  databasename  < path/example.sql